# Convert byte array to int32

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem to convert byte array to int32 via BitConverter.ToInt32.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
> mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the > collection. Check array index and length

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] StrToByte = new byte[9];
    int IntHexValue;           
    StrToByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
    textBox4.Text = BitConverter.ToString(StrToByte);
    IntHexValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(StrToByte, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you allocating a 9 byte array, and then ignoring it? (You're assigning a new value to `StrToByte`.) What's the contents of `textBox2.Text`? It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: What is the value of `textBox2.Text` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül, Why? Are you Looking for another shell command? `:)`

Comment: `BitConverter` applied to UTF-8 data....? just: ***why***? what is it that you are trying to **achieve**? Because unless the requirements are really really odd, that is not a valid way to do it...

Comment: @gdoron Yeap! Go to `run` and type `BitConverter.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text) -quickly` and everything is ready `:)`

Answer (score 7):

Presumably the UTF-8 representation of the text in `textBox2` is fewer than 4 bytes long. `BitConverter.ToInt32` requires 4 bytes of data to work with.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, by the way - but using `BitConverter.ToInt32` on encoded text is rarely a useful thing to do.

Also, in terms of coding style:

- You're allocating a new byte array, but then effectively ignoring it
- You're declaring variables before you actually use them, for no reason. (Ideally declare variables at the point of first use)
- Your variables don't follow .NET naming conventions, where they would be camelCased and ideally giving more of an indication of meaning rather than just the type

So even if your code *were* actually correct, it would be better written as:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
    textBox4.Text = BitConverter.ToString(encodedText);
    int leadingInt32 = BitConverter.ToInt32(encodedText, 0);
    // Presumably use the value here...
}
```

(As I say, it's not clear what you're really trying to do, which is why the name `leadingInt32` isn't ideal - if we knew the meaning you were trying to associate with the value, we could use that in the variable name.)

Comment: I trying convert bytes to int (like 0x31, 0x32, 0x33 to integer 0x7B (1 is 0x31, 2 is 0x32, 3 is 0x33, 123 is 0x7B))

Comment: @user2955372: But what is the text here? And did you read the documentation for `BitConverter.ToInt32` first?

Comment: @gdoron: Have added various style notes.

Comment: textBox2.Text value content any text you can print via text box.

Comment: @user2955372: But what do you expect that value to *mean*? And what do you want to happen if it's less than four bytes when encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score 3):

Reason of this error is that `BitConverter.ToInt32` expects byte array of at least 4 elements, but you pass to it result of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text)`, which can be less than 4 bytes if user typed something short to your `textBox2`, for example "123" - it will be only 3 bytes.
As a workaround for your scenario you should pad byte array to at least 4 bytes long, something like this:

```
    StrToByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123");

    if (StrToByte.Length < 4)
    {
        byte[] temp = new byte[4];
        StrToByte.CopyTo(temp, 0);
        StrToByte = temp;
    }

    IntHexValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(StrToByte, 0);
```